# Models Mixin ManytoMany

Tags: python, django

I want to implement in django a model mixin. I have in

**mixin.py:**

```
class RightsModelRelation(models.Model):

    user_link = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, default=None,
                                    related_name="%(class)s_rights_user")
    right_to_view = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    right_to_change = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    right_to_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class RightsModelMixin(models.Model):

    rights_link = models.ManyToManyField(RightsModelRelation, default=None,
                                         related_name="%(class)s_rights_link")
```

**models.py:**

```
class Address( RightsModelMixin,models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", )
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True, null=True)
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help me implement a manytomany models mixin?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you should create an `abstract` model. It's table will never be created you can use it just like python base class - so it matches your case. More on that in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)